# Video.JS Flash Source FLA Available?

Tags: video.js

I am trying to use Video.JS in an environment that requires ADA Compliance.  Part of this is the capability to tab through and activate all video controls in both Flash and HTML5 versions of the player.  The performance of the built-in tabbing of Video.JS is pretty buggy, especially in Flash.  I am hoping to get my hands on the FLA and source code of the Video.JS flash player so I can tweak the tabbing behavior.  Does anybody have any idea where I could find it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source for the swf component is on Github: https://github.com/zencoder/video-js-swf

Comment: Nice, thank you!  Makes sense that there is no .FLA and it's a Flash Builder project.